# Visual Studio 2010 portable class library won't let me change the target

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I'm trying to make a portable class library in VS2010.  By default, it seems to be targeting `.NET Framework 4 and higher`.  I need to target 4.03 or higher because I need  some features that were added (`System.Xml.Linq`).  But when I try to change the target framework, the change doesn't work.  I get this dialog:

[image: Change Target Framework Dialog]

I can choose one of the other frameworks and say `OK`, but when I look again, it's set back to the same Framework 4.0 setting, and my code using the 4.03 features still doesn't compile.  What's going on here?

**Update**: It does let me choose 4.5 as long as I don't choose `Mono for Android` or `VS Mono Touch`.  It looks like something in those libraries requires 4.0, but I don't understand why, since 4.5 is backwards compatible.  And this is for use in Mono, so I need those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out with some hacking of the configuration files for the portable framework.  First, [read this post](http://jpobst.blogspot.com/2012_04_01_archive.html) about how to add library support for PCL's for MonoDroid and [this one](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2012/09/mvvmcross-vnext-portable-class.html) to do a similar thing for MonoTouch.

In the .csproj file for the PCL project, I found this line:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile95</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

which points to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile95
```

In that folder, there's a subfolder called `SupportedFrameworks` and this was missing the magic files `MonoAndroid,Version=v1.6+.xml` and `VSMonoTouch,Version=v1.0+.xml`.  I added these, as described in the linked post, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the ability to pick and choose the PCL profile constraints in MonoDevelop in git master, but it has not yet been released.

I believe these features will be included in MonoDevelop 3.1.0

Comment: Is there any ETA for MD 3.1.0?

Comment: another week or 2 I would guess