# Can I reference .NET 4.0.3 runtime in MonoDevelop on a Mac?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In [my question about using .NET 4.0.3 in a Portable Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683848/visual-studio-2010-portable-class-library-wont-let-me-change-the-target) I spoke a little too soon: I got the PCL working on my Windows machine, but now I can't get it working on the Mac.  If the library is set to use .NET 4.03, I get compiler errors in MonoDevelop, saying that the framework is not supported.  So I'm stuck on PCL for .NET 4.0, which is annoying because I need some features from 4.0.3.

So, is there a way to target .NET 4.0.3 in MonoTouch/MonoDevelop **on the mac**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop (up through 3.0.6) is/was hard-coded to *only* work with PCL Profile1 (I think it was Profile1, anyway). As a workaround, you can try changing over to Profile1 and building that.

On MacOS, MonoDevelop simply links with MonoTouch (or Mono4Android) system assemblies and ignores the PCL profile constraints (other than verifying that the profile is Profile1). If MonoTouch has the 4.0.3 APIs that you are trying to use, then things will build fine.